# Printing the actual field delimiter value not the regular expression

Tags: regex, awk, delimiter, gawk

Given the following input:

```
check1;check2
check1;;check2
check1,check2
```

and the `awk` command:

```
awk -F';+|,' '{print $1 FS $2}'
```

`FS` should contain the selected delimiter?

How can you print the delimiter which is selected *i.e.* either of `;`, `;;` or `,` not the regular expression that the describes the delimiters.

If the input is `check1;check2` then the output should be `check1;check2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think awk stores the matched delimiter anywhere. If you use GNU awk, you can do it yourself:

```
gawk '{match($0, /([^;,]*)(;+|,)(.*)/, a); print a[1], a[2], a[3]}'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using GNU Awk (gawk) you can use the 4th argument of `split()`:

```
gawk '{split($0, a, /;+|,/, seps); print a[1] seps[1] a[2]}' file
```

Output:

```
check1;check2
check1;;check2
check1,check2
```

Using it within a loop is also easy to handle:

```
gawk '{nf = split($0, a, /;+|,/, seps); for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i) printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]; print ""}' file

22011,25029;;3331,25275
6740,16516;;27292,1217
13480,31488;;7947,18804
328,30623;;12470,6883
```

If you only need the fields you would only have to touch `a`. Separators would be separated in `seps` and the indices of those are aligned with `a`.

Comment: That was a useful and detailed answer, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

GNU awk has this feature for records not fields so you could also do something like this:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' RS=';+|,|\n' file
check1;check2
check1;;check2
check1,check2
```

Where `RT` is the value match by `RS` for the given record which you can see by:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s",RT}' RS=';+|,|\n' file
;
;;
,
```